# BUG: theApp.GetSectionString() does not return default value

Tags: c++, mfc

I use the `theApp.GetSectionString(lpszSubSection, lpszEntry, lpszDefault)` to read Values from the Registry.

The problem is that it does not return a default value if the target entry is missing in the Registry.

`CString str = GetSectionString(_T("Settings"),_T("Gugus"),_T("default 123"));`

I does always check `str` and if it is an empty string then it manually sets the default value to the `str`.

Is this a bug or default behavior of `GetSectionString()`?

```
    CString str = theApp.GetSectionString (_T("Xenax"),_T("MechanicalLimit X-,X+,-Y-,Y+"), "-20999, 4799, 2699, -9999" );
    if (str.empty())  // <- Needed, :(( 
    {
        str = "-20999, 4799, 2699, -9999"   ;  
    }
```

Comment: There was a bug in `CWinAppEx::GetSectionString()`. This bug was fixed in VS 2012

Comment: Yes, I am using VS2010.  Is there a workaround for this problem in VS2010?

Comment: You'll have to update to VS 2012 or higher version of VS or use that workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code should read (`IsEmpty()` should be used instead of `empty()`):

```
CString str = theApp.GetSectionString (_T("Xenax"),_T("MechanicalLimit X-,X+,-Y-,Y+"), _T("-20999, 4799, 2699, -9999") );
if (str.IsEmpty())  // <- Needed, :(( 
{
    str = _T("-20999, 4799, 2699, -9999");  
}
```

There was a bug in `CWinAppEx::GetSectionString()`. This bug has been fixed in VS 2012. More info at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/14/10320171.aspx

Comment: Yes, I see the problem in 
   BOOL CSettingsStore::Read(LPCTSTR lpszValueName, CString& strValue)

I was not sure if this is a bug or default behavior, because the same problem with theApp.GetString(..)